# Instal pecl_http: raphf installed but ./configure isn't seeing it

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to install pecl_http as an extension to php.

phpise is working fine as I'm getting the configure file out. When I go to type ./configure I get the following error message;

```
...
checking openssl/crypto.h usability... yes
checking openssl/crypto.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/crypto.h... yes
checking for gnutls support in libcurl... no
checking for ares support in libcurl... no
checking for bundled SSL CA info... /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking for event2/event.h... found in /usr
checking for libevent version, roughly... 2.0.19-stable
checking for ext/raphf support... no
configure: error: Please install pecl/raphf and activate extension=raphf.so in your php.ini
```

I've added the following line to my php.ini file

```
extension=raphf.so
```

I know raphf is installed and loading as I've checked it with the following php:

```
echo extension_loaded(raphf) ? "raphf loaded" : "raphf not loaded";
```

Which comes back it is loaded.

Why is ./configure not seeing raphf?